# what are the advantages of angularjs over jsp and vise versa

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, jsp

1. Give me couple of advantages of angularjs over jsp.
2. Give me couple of disadvantages of angularjs over jsp.

Comment: I don't get your question JSP over angular does it make any sense ?..

Comment: @M Balajivaishnav it is simply what is the difference between angularjs and jsp. Hope question is clear. And it make sense for me as question is clear to me, I wonder why its not clear to you. Or tell me why it doesn't make sense for you, is that it is not possible to do a comparison between those two technologies ?

Comment: if your question was clear then why your getting down votes just google it

Comment: @  M Balajivaishnav, only people who down votes can answer your question, so I invite them to comment here and explain where it is not clear if not clear or any other reason if you have. At least  M Balajivaishnav can explain where it is not clear to you. (@ M Balajivaishnav if you decide question clearness based on number of down votes its wrong, as some may down vote it for some other reason,)

Comment: I think there is no other reason for down votes if your question is not clear people surely will down vote it nothing much more

Comment: @ M Balajivaishnav , if question is " advantage of angularjs over jsp", only three thing you want to know
1. meaning of the word "advantage"
2. what is angularjs
3. what is jsp
if above three clear to you, then question "advantage of angularjs over jsp" should be clear, but if any of above three not clear to you, then I agree question is not clear to you

Comment: You are comparing a server side with a client side framework which itself doesn't make any sense, if you have googled this basic thing you could have got many resource link, the question itself says that you did not take any research effort

Comment: I agree with your point of research effort. But do not agree with your point of "doesn't make any sense", reason, assume some body asked you "what is the difference between server and browser" as he doesn't know much about server or browser. According to you, for sure you will say that question doesn't make sense. But what need to say , this is what server means and this is what browser means and they are in two different ends so advantages of a browser is browser can do these, what server can not do.That's how to help others to understand stuff rather than throw their questions to dust bin

Comment: My other point is even one is server side technology and other is client side technology, it doesn't block you to find out what advantages having with angularjs over jsp, because both used to create presentation layer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference between Angular and JSP is where the work carried out - if you want a web application with lots of user interaction and page state or single page application (it is when there are actions without page reloading) - AngularJS may be the best choice. Also if you want to segragate client side from server side - Angular would be better too. If you want pages with simple, fixed interactions, without dynamic state updates - JSP will be better.